# Bokeh hover tool showing '???' instead of ColumnDataSource value

Tags: python, bokeh

[image]I am trying to add a hover tooltip to my bokeh plot. The tooltip shows up, but the area value I am trying to display shows up as '???'. I am using ColumnDataSource to set the plot source data, and area is a valid column in that data source. I can't figure out why the plot can't fine the area values.

```
source = ColumnDataSource(data=df.groupby('state').sum())
TOOLTIPS = [("area", "@%area")]
p = figure(x_range=source.data['state'], width=1300, height=1000)
p.vbar(x=source.data['state'], top=source.data['area'], width=.5)
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=TOOLTIPS))
```

Answer (score 6):

The issue is Bokeh allows for two different ways of providing data to a glyph. But only one way works with a tooltip, if the tooltip references a column in the data.
This line:

```
p.vbar(x=source.data['state'], top=source.data['area'], width=.5)
```

Should be changed to:

```
p.vbar(x='state', top='area', width=.5, source=source)
```

Comment: Additionally, passing a `groupby` to the ColumnDataSource makes the source contain columns for the group aggregations, that may be an issue here as well.

Comment: You can certainly have tooltips with both ways, including the first above. But in that case the columns names are the defaults, e.g. `"x"`, not `"state"`